# Mixing time of combined Markov Chains

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, mixing

Let $P_1,...,P_k$ denote the transition matrices of $k$ irreducible, aperiodic Markov Chains on finite state spaces $S_1,...,S_k$ all of them being disjoint. Hence, there are stationary distributions $\pi_1,...,\pi_k$ such that $\nu_iP_i^k\to \pi_i$ for any initial distribution $\nu_i$. Denote the corresponding mixing times by $t_i$.

Define by $P=\mathrm{diag}(P_1,...,P_k)$ a stochastic block diagonal matrix. Then $P$ can be seen as a transition matrix for a Markov chain on the state space $S=S_1\times...\times S_k$ and converges for a given initial distribution $\nu$ on $S$ to $\pi = (\nu(S_1)\pi_1,...,\nu(S_k)\pi_k)$.
I am wondering what I can say about the mixing time $t$ of the chain $P$. Intuitively it should be something like the $\max\{t_1,...,t_k\}$ since "the slowest chain" amongst the $P_i$ should dominate the convergence speed of $P$ but I am not really making any progress on showing this.

Maybe my claim is even wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Definition mixing time:

$t_m=\inf\left\{t\in\mathbb{N}:\max_{x\in S}||P^t(x,\cdot) - \pi||_{TV}<\dfrac{1}{2}\right\}$.

Comment: What is your definition of mixing time?

Comment: Added the definition in EDIT.

Comment: Something is weird with your description: if all individual state spaces have size 2, the combined state space has size $2^k$ but your “block transition matrix” has only $2k$ rows.

Comment: That's true... I wanted to express something of the sort $S=\{(s_1,s_2,...,s_k)| s_i\in S_i\}$. But my notation is false. 
PS: I am confused...

Comment: I also do not understand notation for $v(S)$ and how P seems both a matrix and a function of x and dot.

Comment: Taking $P=\mathrm{diag}(P_1,...,P_k)$ seems like the transition matrix for a Markov chain with $k$ connected components, each one isomorphic to one of your original Markov chains. The mixing time (and the limiting distribution) depends on which component you start in, and then it will just be the mixing time for the corresponding Markov chain.

Comment: @MishaLavrov yes, thank you that is exactly what I wanted to express. So the mixing time of $P$ will depend on the initial condition and is therefore a random variable itself?